# Autocompletion for Panda3D in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, panda3d

Autocompletion doesn’t work for Panda3D 1.10.11. in VSCode 1.68.1. Is it possible to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[unware](https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d/issues/1327#issuecomment-1208047611):

> You can download the folder https://github.com/WMOkiishi/types-panda3d/tree/master/src/panda3d-stubs with https://download-directory.github.io/ , name it `panda3d-stubs` and add the directory containing it to the VSCode's settings.

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\panda3d\\stubs"
]
```

For example:

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "E:\\Libs\\panda3d"
    ]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the lack of `.subs` files in `panda3d` package, not vscode. Related [problem](https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d/issues/1327) has been raised in GitHub. Please wait for the update of package.